# Get Access token for multiple organizations

Tags: xero-api

Is there any way I could get an access token for multiple organizations in public or partner applications?

Comment: Both public & private apps give you access to multiple organisations, as long as the organisations' owners authorise the application: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/api-application-types

Comment: a single token is for single  organization I think. My question was can I have a single token for multiple organization access or can the organization owner give me access to multiple organizations in one go? If it is yet not clear then please tell I will elaborate with example

Comment: No - you need a token for each organisation for which your app has authorisation.